# SQL Database Login Failed

Tags: sql-server, login

The SharePoint logs, as well as in the event viewer keep popping up the following error:

'SQL database login for 'DBTable' on instance 'DatabaseServer' failed. Login failed for user 'domain\WebServerMachine$'

The strange thing is that I can access and return data from the database. All the webpages load fine.

I just can't seem to get rid of this error. Any Ideas?

Comment: Service Accounts?

Comment: In what sense are you talking? I am using Windows authentication

Comment: did you used NetworkService for any Service Accounts - e.g in the case of Web Application Pools?

Comment: The SharePoint application pool account in IIS is set to 'DomainName\SPAdmin'

Comment: You still need to make these changed in central administration

Comment: I did make these changes. And in the db server, this account is set as db_owner for all sharepoint databases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to you having localSystem as a service account that accesses the database.. on the database in question add the user domain\machinename$ to the security group... I wouldn't recommend this because this is a highly priviledged account. it is best to create a new service account and change the service account sharepoint uses in central administration and give that account the necessary permissions to your database which is usuall DbOwner and dbBackupOperator

Comment: Are you referring to the 'Claims to Windows Token Service'?

Comment: All my services are configured in the 'Configure Service Accounts' to use an account 'SPAdmin', instead of 'Local System'. That account is db_owner on all SharePoint db's. I am still getting the error.

Comment: I am not absolutely sure but i know that account you were referencing is a localsystem account. One of your services are configured to use that account. check central administration and the services area on your win2k8 box. it would use SPAdmin if it were configured to use it.. make sure you are not overlooking a service.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All the service accounts are configured to use my 'domain\SPAdmin' account. And I did an IIS Reset. I don't see what else there is to do

Comment: Ok one more check look at the ULS log and try to see what is occurring before and after that error and see if it is relative to a service. Do you have any SQL Aliases setup

Comment: It fails in the ULS Log when the command 'Get-SPContentDatabase' is run, then the login failed error prompts

Comment: Are the app pools that sharepoint uses in IIS use the spadmin account?

Comment: I have fixed the issue. There was insufficient privileges. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Glad you did let me know if you need help again

Answer (score -1):

Change impersonate to false in web config file. By default it will be true. identity `impersonate="false" />`

Comment: Would you be able to add some more information please :) ,  like what could be the possible location of web.config file. So that it will be easy for users to track.